# How to parse two strings using boost::spirit?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

I am still trying to wrap my head around Boost::Spirit.
I want to parse two words into a variable. When I can do that, into a struct.
The single word compiles, the Variable doesn't. Why?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::spirit;

/*
class Syntax : public qi::parser{

};
*/

int main()
{
    //get user input
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    auto it = input.begin();

    bool result;
    //define grammar for a single word
    auto word_grammar = +qi::alnum - qi::space;

    std::string singleWord;

    result = qi::parse(
        it, input.end(),
        word_grammar,
        singleWord
    );

    if(!result){
        std::cout << "Failed to parse a word" << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "\"" << singleWord << "\"" << '\n';

    //Now parse two words into a variable
    std::cout << "Variable:\n";
    typedef boost::tuple<std::string, std::string> Variable;
    Variable variable;
    auto variable_grammar = word_grammar >> word_grammar;

    result = qi::parse(
        it, input.end(),
        variable_grammar,
        variable
    );

    if(!result){
        std::cout << "Failed to parse a variable" << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "\"" << variable.get<0>() << "\" \"" << variable.get<1>() << "\"" << '\n';

    //now parse a list of variables
    std::cout << "List of Variables:\n";
    std::list<Variable> variables;

    result = qi::parse(
        it, input.end(),
        variable_grammar % +qi::space,
        variable
    );

    if(!result){
        std::cout << "Failed to parse a list of variables" << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    for(auto var : variables)
        std::cout << "DataType: " << var.get<0>() << ", VariableName: " << var.get<1>() << '\n';

}
```

In the end I want to parse something like this:

```
int a
float b
string name
```

Templates are nice, but when problems occur the error messages are just not human readable (thus no point in posting them here).
I am using the gcc

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer this. I would if it were x3. Personally, I would use x3 as it compiles so much faster and is easier to deal with. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48803123/how-to-parse-a-string-into-vector-of-tuples-with-boost-spirit) should help. I got it to compile with a qi::rule and using `std::tuple` instead of `boost::tuple`

Comment: @lakeweb Can you elaborate on how you used the qi::rule? Also how do I change to x3? Don't shy away from posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to take so long. I've been building a new web server in a hurry and had much to learn.

Here is what it looks like in `X3`. I think it is easier to deal with than `qi`. And then, I've used it a lot more. But then `qi` is much more mature, richer. That said, `x3` is meant to be adaptable, hackable. So you can make it do just about anything you want.

So, [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6895b80cc9e521c)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
//as pointed out, for the error 'The parser expects tuple-like attribute type'
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>

//our declarations
using Variable = boost::tuple<std::string, std::string>;
using Vector = std::vector<Variable>;

namespace parsers {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    auto const word = lexeme[+char_("a-zA-Z")];
    //note, using 'space' as the stock skipper
    auto const tuple = word >> word;
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, /*const*/ Variable& obj) {
    return os << obj.get<0>() << ' ' << obj.get<1>();
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, /*const*/ Vector& obj) {
    for (auto& item : obj)
        os << item << " : ";
    return os;
}

template<typename P, typename A>
bool test_parse(std::string in, P parser, A& attr) {
    auto begin(in.begin());
    bool r = phrase_parse(begin, in.end(), parser, boost::spirit::x3::space, attr);
    std::cout << "result:\n " << attr << std::endl;
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    //not recomended but this is testing stuff
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    using namespace parsers;

    std::string input("first second third forth");

    //parse one word
    std::string singleWord;
    test_parse(input, word, singleWord);

    //parse two words into a variable
    Variable variable;
    test_parse(input, tuple, variable);

    //parse two sets of two words
    Vector vector;
    test_parse(input, *tuple, vector);
}
```

You may like this form of testing. You can concentrate on testing parsers without a lot of extra code. It makes it easier down the road to keep your basic parsers in their own namespace. Oh yea, `x3` compiles much faster than `qi`!

Comment: Sorry that I took so long to finally analyze your code. Thank you so much for the details and suggestions. This will serve me as a good reference!

Answer (score 1):

> The single word compiles, the Variable doesn't. Why?

There are missing two #includes:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_list.hpp>
```

Comment: I was able to compile, yet it fails to parse a variable. How would you approach it? lakeweb in the comments mentioned qi::rule?

Comment: If you want to parse into struct then you will need grammar/rule. There is good [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html)